# Node's Express, run a Model method on a collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So I have a simple query:

```
var query = postModel.find({ //etc });
query.exec(function(err, posts) {

});
```

Then I have a Model method:

```
PostSchema.method('deepPopulate', function(cb) { //stuff });
```

In my other finds, I can do stuff like so:

```
post.deepPopulate(function(err, post) {});
```

Which works fine for a `findOne()`, but how can I run the same Model function on a collection of posts in the result of a `find()`?

Comment: `postModel.find().forEach( function(){} );` ? Is this in Mongo or Node?

Comment: Sorry, this is Node but using mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library's [map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) method. It's probably possible with promises too.

```
async.map(posts, function (post, done) {
  post.deepPopulate(done);
}, function (err, posts) {
  // ... do yaw thang
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't using the `lean` property for your query each result should be a model object with the method `deepPopulate()`:

```
var query = postModel.find({ //etc });
query.exec(function(err, posts) {
  for each ( var post in posts ) {
    post.deepPopulate(); //Or however you use this guy.
  }
});
```